# How to set the physics property of imported mesh in Blender

Tags: physics

everyone,
I am trying to add rigid body properties to a mesh model in Blender. There are a lot of tutorials available on how to set rigid body property of the Blender built-in mesh models such as cube. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNDO2xvUHtc) to do the same thing in a imported mesh model.

However the weird thing is that the built-in cube falls normally on the passive plane but the imported mesh model just falls through the passive plane. Is there anything special to be set in order to make the imported mesh also work normally?

Thanks very much. I put on [blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7d8jq83yit5p8h/physics.blend?dl=0) here and I use Blender 2.79 on windows 10. I am sorry that the file size is large since the imported mesh model is very large.

Comment: Try to add thickness to the plane

Comment: @Denis I tried to use extrude to add thickness to the plane, however the mesh model still falls through it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured it out. It turns out that the mesh model is too complicated. I need to first use the Decimate Modifier to simplify it. Then it works normally, although with some vibrating effect.

Comment: If the model is too complex but you still want to use it for rendering the simulation, you could also simulate with an object with simple geometry and parent the complex model to it.